# PHP post checkbox problem

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

i have a form that utilizes checkboxes.

> `<input  type="checkbox"  name="check[]"  value="notsure">  Not Sure, Please help me determine <br />
>               <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="keyboard"> Keyboard <br />
>               <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="touchscreen"> Touch Screen Monitors <br />
>               <input  type="checkbox"  name="check[]"  value="scales">Scales <br />
>               <input  type="checkbox"  name="check[]"  value="wireless">Wireless Devices <br />`

And here is the code that process this form in a external php file.

```
$addequip = implode(', ', $_POST['check']);
```

I keep getting this error below;

```
<b>Warning</b>:  implode() [<a href='function.implode'>function.implode</a>]: Invalid arguments passed in <b>.../process.php</b> on line <b>53</b><br />
OK
```

Comment: Why do you want to implode the array?

Answer (score 1):

is any of your checkboxes ticked? php’s `$_POST` array will only have checkboxes which have been ticked

to silence your warning use this:

```
$addequip = implode(', ', empty($_POST['check']) ? array() : $_POST['check'] );
```

Comment: i m getting the same error even though the check box are checked. I tried the method from http://www.kirupa.com/web/php_contact_form3.htm still no dice

Comment: are you sure, you are using post method on the form? default (no attribute) is get

Answer (score 0):

the following site seems to be what you need:

http://www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/desperate-gettin-checkbox-values-post-php-t28756.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi I m the original user who posted this question i couldnt login to my account so posting from another account. After couple hours of trying i somehow managed to make it work partially. Below is the modified form html and process code for checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Touchscreen"> Touchscreen<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Keyboard"> Keyboard<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Scales"> Scales<br>
```

I had to remove the [] so it would work. Also below is the entire post method for those would like to see. It works perfectly fine with every other field.

```
<form id="contact_form" action="process.php" method="POST" onSubmit="return processForm()">
```

And below is the php code to process checkboxes. For some reason i have to tell script that $_POST['check'] is an array without it would only return array. All other methods suggested returns invalid argument passed error.

```
$chckbox = array($_POST['check']);
                if(is_array($chckbox))
                {
                  foreach($chckbox as $addequip) {
                  $chckbox .="$addequip\n";
                  }
                }
```

So this code works but returns only 1 checkbox value that is ticked even no matter how many you ticked.

Comment: What happens if you take the onSubmit="return processForm()" out of your form tag?  It's possible that javascript is causing the issue.

Comment: No it makes no difference for form submission still getting only one value. It is used for captcha class i m using ajax so the page submission doesnt open another page and form is cleared once submission is done.